# Placing all labels in ArcMap non-overlapped by extending arrow/line from label to point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, labeling, annotation

I was wondering if there is a way to place all labels on a map non overlapping, but by extending an arrow/line from the label to the point.

I've tried the call out box, but I couldn't find a way to enable all labels, and second extend the lines

Comment: I answered a similar question to yours regarding using label leader lines, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14913/is-it-possible-to-add-leaders-to-point-symbols-if-they-overlap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the priority and ranking tools on the Labeling toolbar to set your label draw weights.  Another solution is to convert the labels to annotation and then manually move them to the best location.

Comment: I hear you on Annotation, but I'd rather have everything done dynamically, as the we have lots of expressions built into this thing. but is there a way to force ArcGIS to extend the labels by let's say an inch or two?

Comment: There is the Label Manager dialog that you can access from the Labeling toolbar.  It gives you a little finer grained control of your label placement.  You can set offset to a specified unit, inches is one of the choices.