# Place all labels on a map non overlapped

Tags: qgis, labeling

As asked for [ArcMAP by @dassouki](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191/arcgis-place-all-labels-on-a-map-non-overlapped), is there a way to place all labels on a map non overlapping using QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

It will not always be possible to fit all labels with a certain size on a map with given scale.

Using user-defined label placement, users can try to optimize label positions.

Similarly to ArcMap, QGIS new labeling enables the use of different label priority settings for layers.